# Скачать пакеты python для оффлайн установки

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

У меня на работе ограничения и если я скачиваю пакеты с помощью команды pip через командную строку, то с интернета все блокирует служба безопасности. Поэтому мне надо скачать пакеты напрямую, а потом установить в оффлайн режиме с компа. Но не могу найти где их скачать.

Подскажите где можно напрямую скачивать пакеты? Мне нужны tqdm, pandas, numpy, sklearn.metrics, statsmodels, scipy, matplotlib

Comment: https://pypi.python.org

Comment: А вообще, при вашем наборе пакетов, попробуйте дистрибутив [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Ведь у некоторых из перечисленных вами пакетов есть зависимости, которые `pip` сам устраняет.

Comment: @mkkik плохой вариант, Anaconda это хороший вариант для Dev машин, когда на бою это уж чересчур раздутый набор lib, лучше и проще выкачивать нужный lib и установить, ответ Dmitry Erohin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Скачивайте нужные вам пакеты отсюда https://pypi.python.org/
2. Для установки нужно написать `pip install полный_путь_до_имени_файла`

Answer (score 6):

Вы можете использовать `pip`, чтобы скачать нужные пакеты:

```
$ pip download -r requirements.txt --dest dist --only-binary :all:
```

Если машина с интернетом отличается от системы, куда вы ставить хотите, то явно укажите платформу, используя `--implementation`, `--platform`, `--python-version` и другие опции. См. `pip help download`.

Затем перенесите папку `dist` на желаемую машину и установите без обращения на PyPI:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index -f dist
```

В простейшем случае [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) это просто файл с именем пакета на каждой строчке:

```
tqdm
pandas
numpy
scikit-learn
statsmodels
scipy
matplotlib
```

Если платформы совпадают, то вы можете собрать двоичные wheels самостоятельно, если их ещё нет на PyPI:

```
$ pip wheel --wheel-dir=dist -r requirements.txt
```