# Как настроить виртуальное окружение Python для проекта?

Tags: python, virtualenv, .env

При создании виртуального окружения в определенной папке в папке виртуального окружения env, в папке Scripts содержится файл содержатся файлы activate, activate.bat, activate.ps1. В файле activate содержится следующий код:

```sh
VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\Users\a\source\repos\PDF\PDF\env"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/Scripts:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Получается что здесь указано какую переменную окружения добавлять в PATH, которая говорит о том где искать интерпретатор python.exe при активации данного окружения(также в папке Scripts окружения env).
Но если я перемещу окружение в другую папку, то путь прописанный в этом файле останется тем же но интерпретатора там уже не будет, по тому пути.
Я пытался менять путь прописанный в этом файле на новый, но он все-равно продолжает добавлять в PATH старый путь и соответственно пытается искать интерпретатор по старому пути и не находит его, поэтому берет интерпретатор python.exe из глобального окружения, путь к которому тоже прописан в PATH.
Как сделать так, чтобы при переносе окружения путь менялся и чтобы интерпретатор брался из папки Scripts соответствующего окружения?
Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перенос окружения - это не копирование папки `env`. Переносятся только список зависимостей, которые, как правило хранятся в файле `requirements.txt` или `requirements.dev.txt` и т.д.

Хороший пример, почему берутся только зависимости, это развертывание виртуальных окружений на разных ОС. Например, при разработке `django` проекта вы используете `windows`, а итоговый в продакшн развертываете на `Debian`. Если вы перенесете только зависимости, все будет работать, как часы. Если же вы скопируете всю папку, то ваш перенос виртуального пространства в секунду превратится в ад. Такой же подход, очевидно, удобно применять и для одинаковых ОС, и если вы посмотрите на готовые проекты на гитхабе, вы увидитие, что они не содержат директорий с окружениями, а только файл с зависимостями.

Туда куда переносится виртуальное пространство. Оно создается заново, и запускается установка пакетов из файла с зависимостями.

Пример через `pip`

```sh
# где создается проект
py -m venv env
env/Scripts/activate
pip install requests
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Сама папка с виртуальным пространством может быть помещена в `.gitignore`

В новую локацию передается только файл с зависимостями и только

```sh
# куда переносится проект
py -m venv env
env/Scripts/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: спасибо помощь. А можно ли сделать так чтобы при создании окружения пакеты подтягивались с другого окружения а не из сети? Немного странный вопрос, но это необходимо

Comment: @АлександрТрифонов если вы взглянете на файл `requirements.txt` после его создания, то увидите, что это просто перечень модулей с версиями. Вы можете файл подтягивать из git'а, дописывать вручную, да, как вашей душе угодно) вы в другом окружениие сформируйте файл и копируйте его куда угодно

Comment: то есть получается я могу просто в свое виртуальное окружение env скопировать папку с модулем из другого окружения и все будет нормально?

Comment: @АлександрТрифонов нет не будет, это может прокатывать, но я не изучал насколько редко такое может случиться. Не делайте так. Если вам нужно сделать это офлайн, тогда воспользуйтесь на машине с интернетом `pip download -r requirements.txt`. Прочтите документацию по этому поводу в https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/

Comment: @АлександрТрифонов гляньте вот сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693593/209304, там есть пример использования