Проблема импорта
Написал проект на питоне
использовал в основном абсолютные пути в импортах модулей в виртуальной среде все гуд и запускал через консольку unicorn run
собрал в контейнере начало все падать (модули не найдены)
Как сделать так что бы работало и через виртуальную среду и в docker и через запуск python файла

дайте пример использования, пока не очень понятно. Может вот это поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1335678/209304, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1465085/209304
